# How to parse subnodes that depended on parents' information?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bison, yacc

If I write grammar file in Yacc/Bison like this:

```cpp
Module
    :ModuleName "=" Functions
      { $$ = Builder::concat($1, $2, ","); }

Functions
    :Functions Function
      { $$ = Builder::concat($1, $2, ","); }
    | Function
      { $$ = $1; }

Function
    : DEF ID ARGS BODY
      {
          /** Lacks module name to do name mangling for the function **/
          /** How can I obtain the "parent" node's module name here ?? **/
          module_name = ; //????

          $$ = Builder::def_function(module_name, $ID, $ARGS, $BODY); 
      }
```

And this parser should parse codes like this:

```
main_module:
    def funA (a,b,c) { ... }
```

In my AST, the name "funA" should be renamed as `main_module.funA`. But I can't get the module's information while the parser is processing `Function` node !

Is there any Yacc/Bison facilities can help me to handle this problem, or should I change my parsing style to avoid such embarrassing situations ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `bison` feature, but as the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Actions.html#Actions) says, use it with care:

> `$N` with `N` zero or negative is allowed for reference to tokens and groupings on the stack *before* those that match the current rule. This is a very risky practice, and to use it reliably you must be certain of the context in which the rule is applied.  Here is a case in which you can use this reliably:

```
 foo:      expr bar '+' expr  { ... }
         | expr bar '-' expr  { ... }
         ;

 bar:      /* empty */
         { previous_expr = $0; }
         ;
```

> As long as `bar` is used only in the fashion shown here, `$0` always refers to the `expr` which precedes `bar` in the definition of `foo`.

More cleanly, you could use a mid-rule action (in `Module`) to push the module name on a name stack (which would have to be part of the parsing context). You would then pop the stack at the end of the rule.

For more information and examples of mid-rules actions, see the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Mid_002dRule-Actions).

Comment: I've used similar way to push parent nodes' information into a stack. But Yacc/Bison parse children before it reach parents ( normal behavior of a LR parser ? ). So I got a reversed order here, and the stack become useless.

Comment: @snowmantw, that's why you need to use a mid-rule action. The mid-rule action fires when the rule reaches that point, so if you put one after the "=" (or, for that matter, just before it), it will act before the `functions` productions. See link in edited answer.